# ng-repeat inside ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Iam

```js
routerApp.controller('HomePageCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','searchFood','$timeout','$cookies',function($scope,$rootScope,searchFood,$timeout,$cookies){
  
   var a=[];
   $scope.fooditems= {};
   
   
   
  $scope.Fn_LoadTimeslotWise = function(ts){
 $scope.tsfooditems = {};
   
 var longitude = $cookies.longitude;
 var latitude = $cookies.latitude;
 var sdate = $cookies.date;
 var timeslot1 = ts;
    var timeslot2 = timeslot1.substr(0,5);
    var timeslot3 = timeslot1.substr(9,2);
    var timeslot4 = timeslot2 + timeslot4;
    
    var timeslot5 = timeslot1.substr(14,5);
    var timeslot6 = timeslot1.substr(23,2);
    var timeslot7 = timeslot5 + timeslot6;
    
    var timefrom = sdate +" "+ timeslot2;
    var timeto = sdate +" "+ timeslot5;
   // console.log(timefrom);
   //console.log(timeto);
   $scope.tim = '.' + ts;
    $timeout(function(){
  
 searchFood.ChangeTimeSlot(latitude,longitude,sdate,timefrom,timeto).then(function(d){
 $scope.tsfooditems ={};
 $scope.tsfooditems = d[0];
 
 });
   
     });
  }
}]);
```

```html
  <div ng-repeat = "timeslot in timeslots">
      <h1 class="title"> {{ timeslot.date_time }} </h1>
      <div class="row product-list-wrap" ng-init = "Fn_LoadTimeslotWise(timeslot.date_time)">
          <h2 ng-show="showsearchmsg" ng-bind="searchresult"></h2>
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="tsfooditem in tsfooditems ">
          <div class="product-box view view-third">
            <div class="product_img">  <span class="favourite"> <i class="fa fa-heart"> </i> </span>
             <span class="veg"> <img src="images/veg.png"></span><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chefdetails"  id=""><img ng-src="{{tsfooditem.picture}}" width="200px" height="150px" ng-click="Fn_fooddetails(tsfooditem.menu_id)"> </a></div>
            <div class="product-content">
              <div class="product-title">
                <h2 ng-bind="tsfooditem.menu_name | uppercase"></h2>
                <h3 ng-bind="tsfooditem.chef_name"></h3>
              </div>
              <div class="product-rate"><b ng-bind="currency"></b>.&nbsp;<span ng-bind="tsfooditem.cost "></span> </div>
              <div class="product-add"> <span class="bg"> - </span> <span ng-bind="tsfooditem.todays_menu_qty"></span> <span class="bg"> + </span> </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
     
       
      </div>
   </div>
```

using angularjs version1.2.13.I need the below specified output

### o/p

### Timeslot 12.30-4.30pm

oil,
vegetable

### Timeslot 1.30-3.30pm

oil,
meat

I am using two ng-repeat one inside another.But always the array displays only secondtime slot,.ie second overrides firstone .please help,Thanks in advance

Comment: post your json here

Comment: Create a fiddle and provide a link

Comment: Using $scope.fooditems object  to store result.In each iteration it changes.Is  2way binding is the reason??

Comment: the second ng-repeat only applies to the items from the first ng-repeat. Could you add the JSON from the first so we see how the second ng-repeat takes form?

Comment: [[{"menu_id":1,"menu_name":"oil 65","chef_name":"Mahe","cost":26,"todays_menu_qty":2,"avail_datetime":"2016-11-15 12:30:00 PM","expiry_datetime":"2016-11-15 04:30:00 PM"},{"menu_id":2,"menu_name":"vegetable fry","chef_name":"Mahss","cost":34,"todays_menu_qty":3,"avail_datetime":"2016-11-15 12:30:00 PM","expiry_datetime":"2016-11-15 04:30:00 PM"}]]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that with your first ng-repeat, tsfooditems is not an array, it is an object literal. Ng-repeat will only work with arrays. Try changing

```
$scope.tsfooditems ={};
$scope.tsfooditems = d[0];
```

to

```
$scope.tsfooditems = [];
$scope.tsfooditems.push(d[0]);
```

Comment: I meant $scope.tsfooditems.push(d[0]); not  $scope.tsfooditems.push(d). Not sure if this will solve your problem, but it is definitely a necessary step.